# How to avoid from java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException exception during stopping async method

Tags: java

I have some method with render() name which includes very difficult logic and I call it so in my code

```
Future<File> fileFuture = null;
try {
        fileFuture = executor.getThreadPoolExecutor()
                    .submit(() -> render());
            return fileFuture.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            fileFuture.cancel(true);
            throw new MyTimeOutException(e);
        }
    }
```

render() method opens some I/O resources and when job doesn't finish
till timeout I get such error when timeout happens

**java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException**

I investigated this problem and found that this happens because
I/O resources stay still open and Thread cannot be terminated
till these resources won't be closed.

But isn't any way for avoiding this exception
I just need to stop my async method when timeout happens.

and I also want add that I use Spring boot if there is any solution with
Spring please tell me

Answer (score 0):

This exception `ClosedByInterruptException` will be thrown when a thread performing a blocking read or write on an `InterruptibleChannel`, like a `FileChannel`, it's interrupted.

When you call `fileFuture.cancel(true)` the boolean flag indicates that if the task is blocked, the thread may be interrupted. So, as the thread is blocked in a read or write operation it throws a `ClosedByInterruptException`.

If you want to get rid of the `ClosedByInterruptException`, then you `render()` method to tackle with `ClosedByInterruptException`, to end the process gracefully if it's thrown.